# Not getting the value from document.getElementById method

Tags: javascript

```
var binaryValue = document.getElementById('binary');
```

```
function binaryToDecimal() {
    var val = binaryValue.value;
    var result = 0;
    var i = val.length-1;
    var j = 0;
    
    while (i > -1) {
        var y = (Number(val[i])) * (2 ** [j]);
        result += y;
        i--;
        j++;
        console.log(y);
    }
    decimalValue.value = result;
    console.log(binaryValue.value);
}
```

Using the code above, I tried to obtain a value from an input field and do a calculation to convert it to a decimal number. But it doesn't obtain the input value. I tried several times and I am unable to figure out it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get a value from an input field:

```js
var binaryValue = document.getElementById('binary');
function binaryToDecimal() {
  var NumValue = binaryValue.value
  console.log("input value: " + NumValue);
    
  //this is how you convert a binary number to decimal
  console.log("binary number: " + (NumValue >>> 0).toString(2));
    
  //this is how you convert an decimal number to binary
  console.log("decimal number: " + parseInt(NumValue, 2));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="binary" placeholder="insert value"/>
<button type="button" onclick="binaryToDecimal()">Show value</button>
```

Use this example to fix your code.

I also added ways to convert to and from binary numbers.